# Find Locked Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

How can we find which table is locked in the database? Please, suggest.

Answer (score 87):

You can use [`sp_lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx) (and `sp_lock2`), but in SQL Server 2005 onwards this is being deprecated in favour of querying [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx):

```
select  
    object_name(p.object_id) as TableName, 
    resource_type, resource_description
from
    sys.dm_tran_locks l
    join sys.partitions p on l.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
```

Answer (score 8):

[sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238824(SQL.80).aspx)

When reading sp_lock information, use the OBJECT_NAME( ) function to get the name of a table from its ID number, for example:

SELECT object_name(16003073)

EDIT :

There is another proc provided by microsoft which reports objects without the ID translation : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q255596/

Comment: Link is broken, and searching Microsoft's site for sp_lock2 no longer returns anything. I guess they have finally pulled the plug on this approach.