# Why doesn't it work (SQL command in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I'd like to ask you why doesn't this code work? It goes without any error,  even cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns 1 (is it if changes one row in the database), but in the actual database, there's absolutely no change. With other database tables, this code works properly, but I'm also not able to remove a row from this table - it behaves asi it if was "read-only", but I have no idea why - yesterday, everything worked fine and now, it's suddenly stopped working :-(

```
string sConnectionString;

                sConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=\"" + zdielaneInfo.Adresar + "\\rozvrh.mdf\";";
                sConnectionString += "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
                SqlConnection objConn
                    = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
                objConn.Open();



                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", objConn);
                if (zdielaneInfo.Edit)

                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE subject " +
                                        "SET name = @name, day = @day, timeStart = @timeStart, timeEnd = @timeEnd "
                                        + "WHERE id = @id";
                else
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO subject (name, day, timeStart, timeEnd) " +
                                         "Values (@name, @day, @timeStart, @timeEnd)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", txbName.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day", dniNaInt(cbDen.Text)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@timeStart", DateTime.Parse(txbStart.Text)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@timeEnd", DateTime.Parse(txbEnd.Text)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", zdielaneInfo.Id));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                objConn.Close();
```

Comment: If the code worked fine yesterday but, with no changes, doesn't work today, then the issue is not with the code itself but with the SQL Server.

Comment: And what error are you getting? Without any error message we cannot help you. And If you're not getting error, try to use breakpoints to go step by step.

Note: If you're using SQL Server management studio to show your data, try to restart it.

Comment: @user35443:  The second sentence states "It goes without any error."

Comment: is it the update or insert command? both? maybe something with sqlexpress db file path?

Comment: @Austin Salonen: But he can make it to show some errors. For example he can try to get data whitch he tried to update, and he will si if it's showing some error message, or if are data same as before.

Comment: I made some changes in the code, but I don't know how it can influence this code - it's absolutely the same. The bad thing is that there is no error or anything like that - it seems to be working fine - but it doesn't change the database. Why could something like that even happen?

Comment: it's actually both (depends on variable edit), but none of two choices doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried my answer. I think its the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have, but nothing changed - it's weird because I can change another table, but not just this one (I've tried to recreate it, but id didn't help)..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the table is locked.

From [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599453/find-locked-table-in-sql-server), try this:

```
select  
    object_name(P.object_id) as TableName, 
    resource_type, resource_description
from
    sys.dm_tran_locks L
    join sys.partitions P on L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
```

If your table is in the result set you have your answer.

---

Another possibility is the user that you are using to run. Maybe he got privileges revoked.

Comment: If the table were locked, wouldn't the update/delete just hang - waiting on the lock?  Until timeout, which would get an exception (no exception was observed)

Comment: There are so many options in SQL Server :) but run the query and try it out.

Comment: @user1401335 and user privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like mdf file overwrite problem.

You are accessing mdf files that are put in the debug folder and replaced every time you run the application.

Be sure that in your project, if you have the database attached within your solution that you are not overwriting it. So select the mdf file in your solution explorer and make sure that its "Copy to output" is set to "Do not copy", then manually copy over the mdf file to the project\bin\debug folder then run the application.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

STOP using the user instance / attachdbfilename options ([user instance is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx)!). Create your database on a real SQL Server, then connect to it directly with your connection string. Using this deprecated feature means that every time you start up your program you're starting with a *new* copy of the database, and what you inserted yesterday is no longer there - and if you connect to the database using that connection string from two different applications, one is not going to see the data that the other one is changing.