# How do I troubleshoot a query that executes indefinitely?

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I run a Select * query against on my SqlServer table that contains 11801 records, it return 11,292 records and then the query continues to execute for half an hour was the longest I let it run before cancelling. I tried running DBCC checks on the table and database but it doesn't report any problems.

Comment: Check for locks?  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599453/find-locked-table-in-sql-server/599546#599546) may help.

Comment: Can you post the query code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic management views. You definitely hava a lock on your table.

```
select 
       db_name(l.resource_database_id)
       ,object_name(p.object_id)       
       ,*
from sys.dm_tran_locks l
left join sys.partitions p
    on p.hobt_id = l.resource_associated_entity_id
where 1=1
    and object_name(p.object_id) is not null --put in your table name
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.